# Azure Pipeline to re-deploy windows service (stop running service only if currently running)

Tags: azure-pipelines, windows-services

I'm trying to build a release pipeline in devops that re-deploys a windows service to a deployment pool. That is all working quite nicely, the only problem is that when copying the new .exe for the windows-service to its directory I need to stop the windows-service. Currently I just run

```
 sc.exe stop "service name"
```

but if the service is stopped for any reason, this will cause an error ("The service has not been started.").
I therefore need a way to determin if the job is currently running, and only stop it then. The same would go for starting the service, as it has to be in a stopped state to start it again.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I therefore need a way to determine if the job is currently running,
> and only stop it then.

You can Add a PowerShell task before the deploy step to run a script to check the service status, if the service is running, then stop it.

```
$ServiceName = 'service1'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

while ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
{

    Stop-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Service stopping'
    Start-Sleep -seconds 10
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Stopped')
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Stopped'
    }

}
```

> The same would go for starting the service, as it has to be in a
> stopped state to start it again.

Do the same thing to add a PowerShell task running the script to check the service status, if the service is not running, then start it.

```
$ServiceName = 'services1'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

while ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running')
{

    Start-Service $ServiceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Service starting'
    Start-Sleep -seconds 10
    $arrService.Refresh()
    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        Write-Host 'Service is now Running'
    }

}
```

You can write script to do the same things using `SC` commands. [This thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/25081/how-do-i-restart-a-windows-service-from-a-script) for your reference.